# if statement using a query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, if-statement, sql-server-2000

I would like to ask how to perform condition checking using `IF statement` in `SQL`, something like the below examples ..

```
if (select* from table where id = @id) = 1 --if this returns a value

insert statement


else

update statement

go
```

or something similar like using a stored procedure...

```
if (exec SP_something 2012, 1) = 0 

insert statement

else

update stement
```

or maybe by using a UDF in the sql statement like...

```
if (select dbo.udfSomething(1,1,2012)) = 0 

insert statement

else

update statement

go
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(1) Using a statement block**

```
IF 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Production.Product WHERE Name LIKE 'Touring-3000%' ) > 5
BEGIN
   PRINT 'There are 5 Touring-3000 bikes.'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
   PRINT 'There are Less than 5 Touring-3000 bikes.'
END ;
```

**(2) Calling stored procedures.**

```
DECLARE @compareprice money, @cost money 
EXECUTE Production.uspGetList '%Bikes%', 700, 
    @compareprice OUT, 
    @cost OUTPUT
IF @cost <= @compareprice 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'These products can be purchased for less than 
    $'+RTRIM(CAST(@compareprice AS varchar(20)))+'.'
END
ELSE
    PRINT 'The prices for all products in this category exceed 
    $'+ RTRIM(CAST(@compareprice AS varchar(20)))+'.'
```

More Examples:

[MSDN 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)
[MSDN 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx)

Comment: @MuhammadHani_ sir, the stored procedure should return a value right? uhm, it is declared as output? the 2 parameters with out and output right sir?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do something like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE ID = @id) = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table SET Name = 'Name' WHERE ID = @id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table (Name) VALUES ('Name');
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example would help you to implement conditional statement using `IF-ELSE`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SetEngineerStock

    @EngineerId INT,
    @PartNumber CHAR(8),
    @NewUnitsHeld DECIMAL(6,2)
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Does stock entry exist?
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EngineerStock
              WHERE EngineerId = @EngineerId AND PartNumber = @PartNumber)

        -- Yes, update existing row
        UPDATE EngineerStock
        SET UnitsHeld = @NewUnitsHeld
        WHERE EngineerId = @EngineerId AND PartNumber = @PartNumber

    ELSE

        -- No, insert new row
        INSERT INTO EngineerStock
        VALUES(@EngineerId, @PartNumber, @NewUnitsHeld)

END
```